# $f$ nonnegative map on $X$ implies $\exists g$ s.t. $S \rightarrow \sum_{\omega \in S} g(\omega) f(\omega)$ is probability measure on $2^X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is exercise 3.3 in Chapter B of [Efe Ok Probability with Economic Applications](https://files.nyu.edu/eo1/public/books.html) (freely available online).

The claim we are asked to prove is :

> Let X be a countably infinite set, and $f$ a nonnegative bounded real map on $X$. Show that there exits a $g \in \mathbb{R}^X_+$ such that the map $S \rightarrow \sum_{\omega \in S} g(\omega) f(\omega)$ is a probability measure on $2^X$

Shouldn't it be "$f$ a **positive** bounded real map on $X$" instead of "$f$ a **nonnegative** bounded real map on $X$"? Otherwise wouldn't the trivial function $~\tilde{f} : X \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\tilde{f}(\omega) = 0$ for every $\omega \in X$ be a counter example? For every $g$, $\sum_{\omega \in S} g(\omega) \tilde{f}(\omega) = 0$ for all $S$. In particular, $\sum_{\omega \in X} g(\omega) \tilde{f}(\omega) = 0 \neq 1$  and the function cannot be a probability measure.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If is sufficient to suppose that $f$ is nonnegative and $f \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, that definitely looks like an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate $X$ as $X=\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$, fix some converging series $\sum\limits_nu_n$ with positive entries, and define $g_t$ on $X$ by $g_t(x_n)=tu_n$ for every $n$, for some positive $t$.

Then $g_t$ is positive everywhere and $\sum\limits_{x\in X}g_t(x)f(x)=t\sum\limits_nu_nf(x_n)$ converges hence a solution is $g=g_t$ with $t=\left(\sum\limits_nu_nf(x_n)\right)^{-1}$.

Or, $f=0$ and then there is no solution.

---

Simpler: take $g(x)=0$ for every $x$ except $g(z)=1/f(z)$ for some unique $z$ such that $f(z)\gt0$.